# Mediaplayer continue to play after app and service dies

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

In my app mediaplayer should continue to play in background. However on some devices, app freezes, when Mediaplayer is started.

After app and corresponding service are killed, mediaplayer continues to play and loops. It will not stop until device restart and there is not trace of mediaplayer service in Running Apps.

Starting app again and making explicit request to stop service does not work to.

How can I finish playback in such situation?

My service look like

```
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Surface;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.squareup.otto.Subscribe;

import java.io.IOException;

import bigdig.yarh.ellotv.GsonModels.VideoDataGSON;
import bigdig.yarh.ellotv.activitytry.R;
import bigdig.yarh.ellotv.activitytry.ui.activity.NavigationDrawerActivity;
import bigdig.yarh.ellotv.broadcastrecievers.CancelPlayBackBroadcast;
import bigdig.yarh.ellotv.broadcastrecievers.NextSongBroadcast;
import bigdig.yarh.ellotv.broadcastrecievers.PlaySongBroadcast;
import bigdig.yarh.ellotv.broadcastrecievers.PreviousSongBroadcast;
import bigdig.yarh.ellotv.bus.BusProvider;
import bigdig.yarh.ellotv.bus.MediaPlayerReset;
import bigdig.yarh.ellotv.bus.NotiControllCancel;
import bigdig.yarh.ellotv.bus.NotiControllPlay;
import bigdig.yarh.ellotv.bus.ProceedViews;
import bigdig.yarh.ellotv.bus.RestartSurface;
import bigdig.yarh.ellotv.bus.SeekBarProgress;
import bigdig.yarh.ellotv.bus.VideoISFinished;

public class MediaPlayerService
        extends Service
         {

             private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
             private static final String TAG             = "MediaService";
             private static final int    NOTIFICATION_ID = 234221;
             private VideoDataGSON videoObject;

             private MediaPlayer player=null;


             @Override
             public void onCreate() {
                 super.onCreate();
                 BusProvider.getInstance()
                         .register(this);
                 mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(
                         NOTIFICATION_SERVICE
                 );

             }


             @Override
             public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

                 createMediaPlayerIfNeeded();
                 Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
                 if (extras == null) Toast.makeText(this, "Media Player Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                         .show();
                 else {
                     videoObject = (VideoDataGSON) extras.getSerializable("videoObject");
                     try {
                         player.setDataSource(videoObject.source);
                         player.prepareAsync();
                     } catch (IOException e) {
                         Log.e("Mediaplayer IO", e.getMessage());
                     }
                 }
//                 Toast.makeText(this, "mediaplayer started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
//                         .show();
                 return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
             }


             @Override
             public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

                 return null;
             }


             @Override
             public void onDestroy() {
                 BusProvider.getInstance()
                         .unregister(this);
                 mNotificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);
                 player.release();
                 player = null;
        super.onDestroy();

    }


    @Subscribe
    public void restartSurface(RestartSurface event) {
        if(player!=null)
        BusProvider.getInstance()
                .post(player);

    }


    @Subscribe
    public void notiCancel(NotiControllCancel event) {
        stopSelf();
    }


    @Subscribe
    public void notiPlay(NotiControllPlay event) {
        try{
        if (player != null) {
            if (player.isPlaying()) {
                player.pause();

            } else player.start();
            createNotification();
        }}
        catch(Exception e){}
    }


    @Subscribe
    public void resetPlayer(MediaPlayerReset event) {
        if (player != null) {
            player.reset();
        }
    }


    @Subscribe
    public void setProgress(SeekBarProgress event) {
        double progress = event.getProgress();

        if (player != null) {
            player.seekTo((int) (player.getDuration() * (progress / 100)));
        }
    }


    @Subscribe
    public void atachSurface(Surface event) {
       if(player!=null) player.setSurface(event);
    }







    public void createNotification() {


        int icon = R.drawable.ic_stat_notify_video;
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        String notiTitle = videoObject.title + " - " + videoObject.getName();
        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, notiTitle, when);


        Intent cancelIntent = new Intent(this, CancelPlayBackBroadcast.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntentCancel = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                this, 9991, cancelIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        );
        Intent previousSongIntent = new Intent(this, PreviousSongBroadcast.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntentPrevious = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                this, 9992, previousSongIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        );
        Intent playSongIntent = new Intent(this, PlaySongBroadcast.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntentPlay = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                this, 9993, playSongIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        );
        Intent nextSongIntent = new Intent(this, NextSongBroadcast.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntentNext = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                this, 9994, nextSongIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        );

        RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.noti_player_controlls);
        contentView.setImageViewResource(R.id.image, R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        if (player != null) {
            if (player.isPlaying()) contentView.setImageViewResource(
                    R.id.noti_play, R.drawable.ic_action_pause
            );
            else contentView.setImageViewResource(
                    R.id.noti_play, R.drawable.ic_action_play
            );
        }
        contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.title, notiTitle);
        contentView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.noti_previous, pendingIntentPrevious);
        contentView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.noti_play, pendingIntentPlay);
        contentView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.noti_next, pendingIntentNext);
        contentView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.noti_cancel, pendingIntentCancel);
        Intent videoIntent = new Intent(MediaPlayerService.this, NavigationDrawerActivity.class);
        videoIntent.addFlags(
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
        );
        notification.contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                MediaPlayerService.this, 0, videoIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        );
        notification.contentView = contentView;

        notification.flags |=
                Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR | Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT; //Do not clear the notification

        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);

    }


    void createMediaPlayerIfNeeded() {
        if (player == null) {
            player = new MediaPlayer();
            player.setOnPreparedListener(
                    new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                            if (!player.isPlaying()) {
                                player.start();
                                BusProvider.getInstance()
                                        .post(new ProceedViews(1));
                                createNotification();
                                BusProvider.getInstance()
                                        .post(player);
                            }
                        }
                    }
            );
            player.setOnCompletionListener(
                    new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                            player.reset();
                            createMediaPlayerIfNeeded();
                            BusProvider.getInstance()
                                    .post(new VideoISFinished());
                            stopSelf();
                        }
                    }
            );
            player.setOnSeekCompleteListener(
                    new MediaPlayer.OnSeekCompleteListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onSeekComplete(MediaPlayer mp) {

                        }
                    }
            );

            player.setScreenOnWhilePlaying(true);
            player.setOnErrorListener(
                    new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {

                        @Override
                        public boolean onError(
                                MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra
                        ) {
                            Toast.makeText(
                                    getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Media player error! What: " + what + "extra :" + extra,
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                            )
                                    .show();
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
            );

        }
    }



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to **return** `STAR_NOT_STICKY` inside the `onStartCommand()` of your `service`. This will **stop your service** once it is interrupted(i.e. service is killed or low memory issue) and will not start it again *automatically*.

Write

```
return START_NOT_STICKY;
```

instead of

```
return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use START_NOT_STICKY in return statement